# Gradle compiles build scripts into a Script-implementing class?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I've read in the Gradle docs, in the page [Learning more about build scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html), the following paragraph:

> When Gradle executes a Groovy build script (.gradle), it compiles the script into a class that implements Script. As a result, builds scripts have access to all of the properties and methods declared by the Script interface.

I don't understand what this means. From what I know, in Java, when a class implements an interface, it needs to implement the methods that the interface declares. How does this fit in here?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle does a lot of "magic" behind the scenes that you don't see for its [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (DSL).

What you see in your Gradle files is a script which is different from a traditional class, so your class rules don't apply, per se.

At its core, Gradle is written in Java. You can see that for yourself by browsing the source [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle). Specifically for the Groovy DSL, Gradle implements a variety of Groovy language features such as [runtime and compile-time metaprogramming](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html).

In particular for the Groovy DSL, Gradle's `Script` class internally implements Groovy's [`Script`](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class) class as seen [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v8.3.0-RC2/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/BasicScript.java#L36). The Groovy' script class states:

> The Groovy compiler will compile the class for you, with the body of the script copied into a `run` method

So the entire contents of your Gradle script, is placed in the `run` method:

```
// script contents
plugins {
    id 'java-library' 
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}
```

--

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

class Main extends Script {     
                
    def run() {                                 
        plugins {
            id 'java-library' 
        }
    
        repositories {
           mavenCentral() 
        }                
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {           
        InvokerHelper.runScript(Main, args)     
    }

}
```

This is a lot more than that, but that is the general gist of it.

Comment: the link you've provided refers to `org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript`. I'm talking about org.gradle.api.Script interface: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Script.html

Comment: @YoavKlein BasicScript (transitively) implements **both** `Script` from Gradle _and_ Groovy. Pay close attention to the different packages used.